# Composite query broken between MySQL 5.1 and 5.6

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a software upgrade script to make for MySQL.

Part of this upgrade involves creating rows in a table for pre-existing entities (the new version of the software creates an extra associated entity for new "parent" entities, while the old version didn't, so I have to create them manually). Children entity IDs are made up basing on a naming convention instead of being an auto-increment surrogate key.

So I was writing this anonymized query:

```
INSERT INTO CHILD_ENTITIES (CHILD_ID, DESCRIPTION, OBJECT_TYPE)
(SELECT 
    CONCAT('PRE_', PARENT_ID, '_SUFF') AS CHILD_ID,
    CONCAT('DESCRIPTION FOR ', PARENT_NAME) AS DESCRIPTION,
    'SYSTEM' AS OBJECT_TYPE
FROM
    PARENT_ENTITIES
WHERE
    CHILD_ID NOT IN (SELECT 
            CHILD_ID
        FROM
            CHILD_ENTITIES));
```

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `CHILD_ENTITIES` (
  `CHILD_ID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OBJECT_TYPE` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CHILD_ID`)
)
```

The query is supposed to select all parent entities from the parent table, manipulate rows to obtain the three only columns of the child entity (note that there is no FK constraint, this is due to DB design) and then insert them into the children. For each parent, a new child is supposed to be created. The `WHERE` clause is a precautional statement, actually written to avoid duplicates but the query is still supposed not to fail in a normal setup even without `WHERE` (because these IDs are generated through a convention and never inserted manually).

**The problem** is that the query works fine on `MySQL 5.1.69-community` as expected, but when run on `5.6.10` (using Navicat, if that matters) it behaves differently: no record is inserted when parent entities exist.

By analysing the query with a few attempts, I discovered that the `WHERE CHILD ID NOT IN ( SELECT CHILD_ID...` is misinterpreted, referring to the subquery's column and not the parent select's column. If I slightly change the query

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('PRE_', PARENT_ID, '_SUFF') AS CHILD_ID,
    CONCAT('DESCRIPTION FOR ', PARENT_NAME) AS DESCRIPTION,
    'SYSTEM' AS OBJECT_TYPE
FROM
    PARENT_ENTITIES
WHERE
    CHILD_ID NOT IN (SELECT 
            CHILD_ID AS DUMMY
        FROM
            CHILD_ENTITIES);
```

Result: `Unknown column 'CHILD_ID' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'`

The error occurs on both versions of MySQL.

So, how should I make such a query to populate children entities starting from parent's ID?

Comment: Not that it necessarily solved your problem but I think it's good practice to identify columns by both column and table (e.g. c.parent_id). Oh and consider providing am sqlfiddle for the above.

Comment: Can you show the `CREATE TABLE` for `PARENT_ENTITIES` as well?

Comment: @ypercube I think that what matters are three columns: PARENT_ID (PK NOT NULL), CHILD_ID (NOT NULL VARCHAR50), SECONDARY_CHILD_ID (NULL VARCHAR50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add a table prefix in all columns and try again:

```
INSERT INTO CHILD_ENTITIES (CHILD_ID, DESCRIPTION, OBJECT_TYPE)
SELECT 
    CONCAT('PRE_', p.PARENT_ID, '_SUFF') AS CHILD_ID,
    CONCAT('DESCRIPTION FOR ', p.PARENT_NAME) AS DESCRIPTION,
    'SYSTEM' AS OBJECT_TYPE
FROM
    PARENT_ENTITIES AS p
WHERE
    p.CHILD_ID NOT IN (SELECT 
            c.CHILD_ID
        FROM
            CHILD_ENTITIES AS c);
```

If that fails with error, too, then it could be a bug. Upgrade to the latest (5.6.13) version and see if it the error persists.

---

Reading the query again, I don't see how it will avoid duplicates. Perhaps you meant to write it this way?

```
---
WHERE
    CONCAT('PRE_', p.PARENT_ID, '_SUFF') NOT IN (SELECT 
            c.CHILD_ID
        FROM
            CHILD_ENTITIES AS c);
```

Comment: Rather than "avoid duplicates" let's say "avoid primary key conflicts". Anyway re-concatenating the strings (using parent ID) works fine. Your first query failed in the answer failed with the same error (CHILD **is** a column of the virtual table made by the seelct projection), but with your second statement I was able to fix. I'll be ok with that.